# Converting a CString to a rapidjson object

Tags: c++, mfc, rapidjson

I have the CString

```
CString strMessage = "{ \n   \"text\":\"This is my message\" \n  }"
```

I was hoping to add that to an existing RapidJson document but as an object. Is there a way to convert the string to an object with out parsing out the data?

```
rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjsonUTF> value;
value.Set(strMessage, document.GetAllocator());
```

But that says no matching overloaded function

EDIT

I figured out a way to do what I was looking for.
Convert the string into a document and then add it as a member to another existing doc.

```
    CString secondJsonString = _T("{ \n   \"text\":\"This is my message\" \n  }");
    GenericDocument < rapidjsonUTF> doc2;
    doc.Parse<0>(jsonString);
    doc2.Parse<0>(secondJsonString);
    doc.AddMember(_T("doc2"), doc2, doc.GetAllocator());
```

Comment: A "c-string" is not the same as an MFT/ATL `CString`. Be careful with your tags.

Comment: Would a cast to `(LPCSTR)` help? `value.Set((LPCSTR)strMessage, document.GetAllocator());`

Comment: Rather than a cast, the `operator .LPCTSTR()` or `.GetString()` members of the `strMessage` object would probably be safer/clearer.

Comment: @AdrianMole clearer - yes, safer - not really, as there is a cast operator defined: `operator PCXSTR() const throw()
 { return( m_pszData ); }`

Comment: GetString() or cast to LPCTSTR will probably work... I say probably... because I don't know what kind of string the value.Set() call needs. It depends on your application whether a CString is a CStringA or CStringW. CStringA is a MBCS string (which Microsoft sometimes calls "Ansi") and is equivalent to characters being char values. Whereas CStringW is a wide string, characters being wchar_t -- a Windows Unicode string. I don't know if the value.Set() expects a const wchar_t*.pointer or a const char* pointer. You can also explicitly instantiate a CStringA or CStringW instead of CString.

Comment: *"no matching overloaded function"* - That's not the full error diagnostic. Please show the full error message. It usually includes the template being instantiated, the template parameters, as well as the candidates.

Comment: @vla `GetString` is safer, too.. `operator LPCTSTR` will compile for `CStringT` instantiations where `XCHAR` doesn't match `TCHAR`. That's a bug and if you are really lucky the results aren't subtle enough to escape testing.

Comment: This isn't creating an object out of my string though it is just setting it as a string.

I am getting 
`{"data":"{ \n   \"text\":\"This is my message\" \n  }"}`

Is there not a way to create an object from the string?